# How do I get the menu item value from the site master page to a another page

Tags: c#

I have a menu, which child menus on my Master page. When the menu opens a second window, I would like to know which option the user selected. Ex: The top level menu is "Edit Existing Item". The child options are" Modify the item status; Modify the item description; Modify the item HTS code.

I have tried just about every article and suggestion I found in the past past seven hours.

On the Site master:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu0" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style7" 
EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" 
Orientation="Horizontal" 
Height="16px" style="margin-left: 20px" Width="215px" BackColor="#99CCFF" 
DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" 
ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" 
OnMenuItemClick="NavigationMenu0_MenuItemClick" >
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit Existing Item" ToolTip="Edit Item already in GP" Value="Edit Existing Item">
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Change Item  Status" ToolTip="Change the status of an item" Value="S" ></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit Item Description" ToolTip="Edit the description of an Item" Value="D"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Change HTS Code" ToolTip="Change the HTS Code of an Item" Value="H"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
```

The code behind on the master page is:

```
protected void NavigationMenu0_MenuItemClick(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
//get the menu option selected by the user
{
    var menu = (sender as Menu);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "alert('Selected Menu is : " + menu + "')", true);

    foreach (MenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.Text);
    }
    var clickedMenuItem = e.Item;
    Session["1"] = e.Item.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/ChangeItem.aspx?=" + e.Item.Text);
}
```

From what I have read, the best way to get the menu value is
On my ChangeItemPage, I have the following:

```
protected void NavigationMenu0_MenuItemClick(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
//get the menu option selected by the user
{
    string ChgItemType = Request.QueryString["value"];
    WebMsgBox.Show("The Menu Item is: " + ChgItemType);
}
```

As a test, I also have it in:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtItemSearch.Focus();

```
    //var menux = (sender as Menu).SelectedValue;
    string ChgItemType = Request.QueryString["value"];
    WebMsgBox.Show("The Menu Item is: " + ChgItemType);
}
```

ChangeItemType value is NULL.

Comment: If I hover over the line:

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
Changing Response.Redirect("~/ChangeItem.aspx?=" + e.Item.Text); to
Response.Redirect("~/ChangeItem.aspx?value=" + e.Item.Value); resolved it.